# Validation error message appears before anything is typed in the text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, validation, input

I am trying to add some validation using jQuery. I have an existing number, when users enter a new number it must be greater than the existing number.

This is my code, but it is giving an error message.

My existing `number.MonoReading`:

```
<div>
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MonoReading)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MonoReading, new {@id="InitialMonoReading", @class = "form", @readonly = "readonly" })
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.MonoReading)
</div>
```

This is the textbox where I will be entering new data. `MonoReading2` (must be more than `MonoReading`):

```
<div>
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MonoReading2)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MonoReading2, new { @id="newMonoReading", @class = "form-add" })
  <div id="MonoErrorMessage"></div>
  @*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.MonoReading2, new { @id="MonoErrorMessage" })*@
</div>
```

I have attempted this, and this is what I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#newMonoReading").focus(function () {
      var str = "";

      var initialMonoReading = $('#InitialMonoReading').val();
      var newMonoReading = $('#newMonoReading').val()
      if(newMonoReading < initialMonoReading){
        $('#MonoErrorMessage').text("New Readings must be less than existing");
      }
      else{
        $('#MonoErrorMessage').text("");
      }
    })
      .change();
  });
</script>
```

The problem with this is it’s not effective at all. It works, but it’s very untidy. When I click the text box it appears straight away even though I haven’t typed anything in. It’s not as fast as well.

Is there another way I can do this?

Comment: What do you mean *"not effective at all"*?

Comment: it works, but its very untidy. when i click the text box it appears straight away even though i havnt typed anytihing in. its not as fast aswell

Comment: Well, you could change the event listener to `.blur` (or `.change`)... And i don't think speed is a problem here to be honest! If it does matter, just cache your elements.

Comment: also when i enter a lower value the error comes up, when i enter a higher value the error is still there!! what should it be instead of blur

Comment: `.focus` should be `.blur` or `.change`.

Comment: it was first .change, but i changed it, because on .change it comes up when i load the page, but i only wanted it to show when i entered a number in the box...

Comment: Well, it come up on the load of the page because you do `.change()` right after. Remove that and it will not show up on load.

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:jquery-validate] tag unless you're asking about the jQuery Validate plugin.  Edited.  Thanks.

Comment: Aside from the event problems, the code shown is comparing the collation order of strings, not numeric values. e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/1qqwv4wj/ Answer updated below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you only really care when you complete editing a value, you can use the jQuery `focusout` event. This tends to be more reliable that the standard `blur` event. Validating on `change` can get irritating for the user if it fires too often:

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/ddc1jgp2/5/

```
$(function () {
    $("#newMonoReading").on('focusout', function () {
        var str = "";

        var initialMonoReading = $('#InitialMonoReading').val();
        var newMonoReading = $('#newMonoReading').val()
        if (~~newMonoReading < ~~initialMonoReading) {
            $('#MonoErrorMessage').text("New Readings must be less than existing");
            $('#MonoErrorMessage').show();
        } else {
            $('#MonoErrorMessage').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

You may actually want to do your check when *either* input changes, and `focusout` supports a parent element, so try this if you want *either input change to validate*:

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/ddc1jgp2/6/

```
$(function () {
    $("#parent").on('focusout', function () {
        var str = "";
        var initialMonoReading = $('#InitialMonoReading').val();
        var newMonoReading = $('#newMonoReading').val()
        if (~~newMonoReading < ~~initialMonoReading) {
            $('#MonoErrorMessage').text("New Readings must be less than existing");
            $('#MonoErrorMessage').show();
        } else {
            $('#MonoErrorMessage').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

**Notes:**

- You are comparing strings for collation order "a" < "b" etc. Convert to integer values.
- `~~` is a shortcut faster conversion of strings to integers. You can also use `parseInt()` if you prefer (with the radix of 10 specified).
- I had to mockup the HTML based on best guess of the generated element.
- The first example could just use `$(this).val()` instead of `$('#newMonoReading').val()` as that is the current *this* element.
- Ignore any comments about *not using* a DOM ready handler as that will make zero difference and is good practice.

Comment: thanks for the information. HOWEVER, your first jsfiddle link is not working. when i enter 1000 for inital reading, am messing around and entered 200000 for new readon, but i still get the error message on your jsfliddle. it doesnt update and hide the error.... arragghh

Comment: You are actually doing string comparisons with `<` :) I will adjust the code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26970867/html-beginform-using-onsubmit-to-validate/26971084?noredirect=1#comment42478662_26971084
any idea about this mate

Answer (score 0):

Don't use onFocus event.  This is firing right away when the page is loaded.  You should instead use onChange event so it's fired only when the user types...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#newMonoReading").change(function () {
        var str = "";

        var initialMonoReading = $('#InitialMonoReading').val();
        var newMonoReading = $('#newMonoReading').val()
        if(newMonoReading < initialMonoReading)
        {
            $('#MonoErrorMessage').text("New Readings must be less than existing");
            $('#MonoErrorMessage').show();
        }
        else
        {
            $('#MonoErrorMessage').hide();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: on .change it appears when i load the page.. thats why i used .focus initially.

Comment: anywhere outside of that function

Comment: Also make sure you don't trigger the onChange event when the page is loaded.

Comment: sorry but i dont understand, you said i shouldnt use .focus but use .change, but you say not to put it in the doucument.ready

Comment: There you go try that.

Comment: actually it works, but when i enter a number that is bigger, the error stays and doesnt go...

Comment: Then you should reset the error message when the input is less than the number...

Comment: when i click back on the textbox and type a low value the error doesnt appear anymore. its not good this way to many problems, thats why am looking for another solution

Comment: You can get rid of the setText and just set #MonoErrorMessage to the error message statically in the html then just use show and hide to show and hide the div or whatever you are using