# Html.BeginForm using onSubmit to validate

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

Am trying to submit a my form , however i have added some jquery for validation which works:

```
    $(function validateForm() {
    $("#newMonoReading").on('focusout', function () {
        var str = "";

        var initialMonoReading = $('#InitialMonoReading').val();
        var newMonoReading = $('#newMonoReading').val()
        if (~~newMonoReading < ~~initialMonoReading) {
            $('#MonoErrorMessage').text("New Mono Readings must be MORE than existing");
            $('#MonoErrorMessage').show();
            return false;


        } else {
            $('#MonoErrorMessage').hide();

        }
    });
});
```

But the problem is on the submit button

```
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
```

If there is an error the submit button still works, i need it to show no error messages and then send, but i tried using the onsubmit for the form but its not working, it still submits even though the value is less and the error message is showing.

This is the html.BeginForm. i think the error may be here. am not really sure.

```
         <div class="modal-body">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "ReadingsEntry", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", onsubmit = "validateForm()" }))
        {
```

Any ideas

Comment: You need to handle the `submit` event, perform the validation and then cancel it if there is an error, but you could just use a [foolproof](https://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[GreaterThan]` attribute

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Is this a correct summary?

> On submit you want to validate your form with your jQuery function.
> If validation is passed then you want the submit to be continued, otherwise you want the submit to be canceled.

If my summary isn't correct, then please clarify your question a bit more.

If I summed it up accurately, you can change your jQuery function to:

```js
$(function validateForm(event) {
  event = event || window.event || event.srcElement;
  var initialMonoReading = $('#InitialMonoReading').val();
  var newMonoReading = $('#newMonoReading').val()
  if (~~newMonoReading < ~~initialMonoReading) {
    $('#MonoErrorMessage').text("New Mono Readings must be MORE than existing");
    $('#MonoErrorMessage').show();
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  else {
    $('#MonoErrorMessage').hide();
  }
});
```

And while creating markup, use following line:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "ReadingsEntry", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", onsubmit = "validateForm(event)" }))
```

Comment: i did this, but now the problem it it gives me an error in the code, saying "was unhandled by user code" but i want it to stay on the form showing the error message

Comment: OK, this is not possible.. event.preventDefault(); will never let the form be submitted. can you please put an alert("Helloo, Validation Failed..!!"); just after the event.preventDefault(); and an other alert("Helloo, Validation Success..!!"); just after $('#MonoErrorMessage').hide();

Comment: let us know, Which one is popped up ??

Comment: why are you using "~~", I never used this one

Comment: ok, when i tried on google chrome it wasnt working, but on ie, it gave me error. it doesnt like         event.preventDefault();

Comment: For IE and Mozilla, you will have to use event = event || window.event || event.srcElement; On the top in the function

Comment: did you include onsubmit = "validateForm(event)" in html.BeginForm() ??

Comment: the only error i get is the erormessage when i type on textbox

Comment: Which of alert is showing ?? is it showing or not ??

Comment: can you please put an alert("Helloo, Validation Failed..!!"); just after the event.preventDefault(); and an other alert("Helloo, Validation Success..!!"); just after $('#MonoErrorMessage').hide();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65068/discussion-between-m-ali-and-pankaj-dubey).

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me

```
function validateForm() {
    if ($('#newMonoReading').val() == 'bla bla bla') {
        alert('bla bla bla');
        return false;
    }

    else {
        form1.submit();
    }


@using (Html.BeginForm("action", "controller", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "form1"}))
{
<input type="text" id="newMonoReading"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick = "return validateForm();" class="btn btn-primary">
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked for me,

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Tag", "Translations",  FormMethod.Get, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", onsubmit = "return validateTagInput()" }))
```

JQuery,

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
   <script>
     function validateTagInput() 
        {
        //do validation
        if (x,y,z)
        {
        return true; //let page be submitted
        }
        else {
        return false; //do not let submission go through
             }
        }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using it this way:

```
  <div class="modal-body">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "ReadingsEntry", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
        {

 <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return validateForm()" class="btn btn-primary">
```

Comment: @m ali : Please check my edited code. It is working. I have verified it.